# Blending Data Sets Google Data Studio (Google Analytics + WordPress)

Tags: regex, wordpress, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to show complex data inside Google Data Studio which includes posts of a WordPress blog and Google Analytics `Pageviews` of them.

Each of these posts has certain `Pageviews` record, so I need to fetch and show them inside a table. Also I need to show `Pageviews` of their AMP version as well.

In order to do that, I connected to the WordPress SQL database inside Google Data Studio. Now I am able to show all posts, on the other side I connected my Google Analytics to show pages with `Pageviews`.

Now I need to bind them with a Join Key. On one side we have page name which is the slug of that page and the other side (on Google Analytics)  we have a path to the page.

Question is how to match the slug with the path name on Google Analytics.

[image]

Sample page name on **Google Analytics**:

```
/mag/post-name
```

or

```
/mag/amp/post-name
```

Sample **WordPress** slug:

```
post-name
```

Is there a way to formulate the condition of the Join Key such as:

```sql
WHEN GA_Page_name is like WP_post_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved using the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below which accounts for a trailing `/` (where `Field` represents the respective Google Analytics field):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"/([^/]*)/?$")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/28552e68-7c1d-4217-93ae-5373c6157bef) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]